# visual studio 2012 gadgeteer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I need to program some .Net Gadgeteer modules for a big project on visual studio 2012.
Unfortunately I can't find the templates for Gadgeteer.
All the tutorial I have found says I have to use visual c# or visual studio 2012.

Do you know if some suitable templates exist?

Answer (score 0):

The templates can be found at the codeplex project. https://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/

Here is a detailed tutorial of setting up the environment. http://gadgeteerguy.com/Tutorials/TutorialView/tabid/147/ArticleId/23/Getting-Started-Guide.aspx